# How to call external commands with parameters on Win7?

Tags: interoperability, external-calls

I'm trying to use the [Win7 command prompt](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true) from a Mathematica notebook.

I'd like to do a couple simple things, but I can't seem to get the syntax straight:

- open explorer.exe in a specific location
- open a command prompt and run several commands

The Wolfram [tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExternalPrograms.html) on external programs says:

> Note that when you use Run, you must not preface commands with
>   exclamation points. Run simply takes the textual forms of the
>   arguments you specify, then joins them together with spaces in
>   between, and executes the resulting string as an external shell
>   command.

This seems to work as it should:

```
Run["C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe"]
```

But this snippet seems to ignore the additional parameters when I call it from Mathematica:

```
Module[{cmd="C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe /e, & \"" <> $UserAddOnsDirectory <> "\""},
  Print@cmd;
  Run[cmd]]
```

even though the syntax as displayed by the `Print` statement is correct syntax and works as expected from the OS command line.

Comment: I recommend using `RunProcess` (and related `StartProcess`, `KillProcess`), much easier to set up complicated command chains. It constructs the actual command to conform to the actual platform it is run on, concerning paths, spaces, escape characters, etc.

Comment: On my system (Win7 x64) all possible forms (`Run["C:/windows/explorer /e"]`, `Run["C:\\windows\\explorer /e"]`, `Run["C:/windows/explorer", "/e"]`, `Run["C:\\windows\\explorer", "/e"]`) work the same way as direct executing from the command line (within the `cmd` process) of the command `explorer /e`: it opens the "My Documents" folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work on Win7 for opening explorer.exe in a specified directory using a command line parameter:

```
Module[{cmd = "C:\\Windows\\explorer.exe /e, \"" <> $UserAddOnsDirectory <>"\""},
Print@cmd;
Run[cmd]]
```

Also, Rui Liu (Wolfram Technical Support) provides [this detailed answer](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/May/msg00457.html) regarding the vagaries of the `Run` command for Windows systems.

Comment: Actually you don't need to use `Run` for opening a specific folder, it is sufficient to use `SystemOpen`, for example `SystemOpen[$UserAddOnsDirectory]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov that's good to know. Looks like `SystemOpen` works for a lot of things as long as the corresponding OS Mime type is set up properly.

Comment: Good point about the fragility of `SystemOpen` (its dependence on the ability of the OS to handle the corresponding MIME type correctly)! I don't know although what corresponds to the *directory path*? The `file://` protocol as in `SystemOpen["file://c:"]`?