# How to get the literal string "{\" foo3 \":\" bar3 \"}" from <|"foo3" -> "bar3"|> --- ( Was: Problem with Run["curl ..."] ... )

Tags: programming, external-calls

**UPDATE: 25-Jan-17 12:02AM CET**

FirebaseLink package does not work on windows

**UPDATE: 25-Jan-17 12:02AM CET**

The problem could probably be reduced to: "How do I get the literal string

```
"{\" foo3 \":\" bar3 \"}"
```

from the association

```
<|"foo3" -> "bar3"|>
```

?"

This makes the problem testable, I suppose.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am working on a notebook where I have to execute external Windows10 commands ( i.e. write data to a Firebase database using curl ). In question [How to call external commands with parameters on Win7?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64931/how-to-call-external-commands-with-parameters-on-win7) I found that I should use

```
Run[command].
```

At the DOS level I want to execute a string in this format:

```
curl -X PUT -d "{\"name\":{\"last\": \"sparrow\"}}" https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/users/jack.json
```

( See also question: [Firebase - How to write using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793426/firebase-how-to-write-using-curl) )

The string

```
"{\"name\":{\"last\": \"sparrow\"}}"
```

must be in JSON format recognizable by Firebase. In my application this data comes from a function which returns a list of associations.

```
ExportString[getBkmkCompEvntMrkt[], "JSON"]
```

So I have

```
curl -X PUT -d
ExportString[getBkmkCompEvntMrkt[], "JSON"], and
https:myfirebasedb/target.json
```

to work with.

Sofar I have consistently failed to get this working.

Please advise.

Comment: `ExportString[<|"foo3" -> "bar3"|>, "RawJSON", "Compact" -> True]`?

Comment: Wow...! Thank you so much. This gives me something to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question arose from using the package [FirebaseLink](https://github.com/keshavsaharia/FirebaseLink). It turned out that this package does not work on Windows(!). I solved the issue here: [Patch for FirebaseLink](https://github.com/keshavsaharia/FirebaseLink/issues/4) if you want to use the package in a windows environment.

Windows requires Run for external programs and does not allow single quotes around the firebase URL.

Answer (score 1):

For your updated question this might work:

```
KeyValueMap[Colon, <|"foo3" -> "bar3"|>]
ToString[%, InputForm]
StringReplace[%, "\[Colon]" -> ":"]
```

> ```
> {"foo3" \[Colon] "bar3"}
>
> "{\"foo3\" \[Colon] \"bar3\"}"
>
> "{\"foo3\" : \"bar3\"}"
> ```

Comment: Thanks. This question got a bit out of hand, really ( also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136166/please-explain-some-unexpected-behavior-of-stringjoin ). - The point is that I had problems with the FirebaseLink package which is a Mac only hack. While modifying the package I came across some of the issues above. - It is all running now.

Comment: The FirebaseLink package is not from Wolfram, it lives on Github.