# Please explain some unexpected behavior of StringJoin

Tags: programming, string-manipulation, external-calls

Consider the following command:

```
StringJoin["curl  -X  PUT  -d  " , ExportString[<|"foo10" -> "bar10"|>, "RawJSON", "Compact" -> True], " https://botX-XXXfb.firebaseio.com/odds10.json"]
```

When I copy the output to a Windows Command window I saw:

```
C:\Users\nilo>"curl  -X  PUT  -d  {\"foo10\":\"bar10\"} \
'"curl  -X  PUT  -d  {\"foo10\":\"bar10\"} \' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\nilo>https://botX-XXXfb.firebaseio.com/odds10.json"
```

Note the "\" at the end of the first line which seems to cause the problem.

Now when I did the same for

```
StringJoin["curl  -X  PUT  -d  " ,ExportString[<|"foo10" -> "bar10"|>,"RawJSON", "Compact" -> True], " Aap"]
```

and copied the output to a Windows Command window I saw:

```
C:\Users\nilo>curl  -X  PUT  -d  {\"foo10\":\"bar10\"} Aap
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Aap; Host not found
```

Note Aap and the -correct- result that the host could not be resolved.

Please explain the unexpected behavior of StringJoin, has this to do with adding a URL string in the Join?

See also question: [question about conversion to JSON](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136158/how-to-get-the-literal-string-foo3-bar3-from-foo3-bar3)

Comment: 100% agreed by OP to put this on hold / delete. This question was a follow-up of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136158/how-to-get-the-literal-string-foo3-bar3-from-foo3-bar3 which is now solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a problem with `StringJoin` but a problem with copy & paste.

Mathematica is adding a line continuation symbol (`\`).  These appear when copying long strings.  You can avoid it using `CopyToClipboard` or Copy As Plain Text.

The version with "Aap" doesn't see the problem because the resulting string is not sufficiently long to require a line continuation.

```
string = StringJoin["curl -X PUT -d ", 
 ExportString[<|"foo10" -> "bar10"|>, "RawJSON", 
  "Compact" -> 
   True], " https://botX-XXXfb.firebaseio.com/odds10.json"]
```

> ```
> curl -X PUT -d {"foo10":"bar10"} https://botX-XXXfb.firebaseio.com/odds10.json
> ```

```
CopyToClipboard[string]
```

And paste into the Windows Command window, or paste into Notepad to see the difference.

[image]

**Edit**

Preserving escape characters.

```
CopyToClipboard[StringReplace[string, "\"" -> "\\\""]]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a manual paste? The curl command has to run 24/7 every 20 minutes.

Comment: It is an incorrect answer ( who are upvoting?? ).
ExportString[{"foo24" -> "bar24"} // ToAssociation, "RawJSON", "Compact" -> True] in your method results in {"foo24":"bar24"}. Note that the \" are now just " .

Comment: The line continuation problem only happens with copy & paste.  How are you intending to use the string in order to run it every 20 minutes.  With [`Run[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html)?

Comment: Yes. Most likely. I scrape data off various websites, aggregate / summarize that data and then store it in Firebase for viewing with a web application.

Comment: There is a package, https://github.com/keshavsaharia/FirebaseLink, which doesn't work on windows either, but I am using it as an inspiration. - I am making progress.