# Opening PDF file on a specific page

Tags: pdf-format, external-calls

Trying to keep track of my Mathematica projects I usually include references to various PDF documents, websites, directories etc. such that I can open them from within the project. In this context I would like to open a fairly large PDF file on a specific page.

I can open Adobe Acrobat Pro 2017:

```
SystemOpen["C:\\Program Files ... \\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe"]
```

I can open the PDF file:

```
SystemOpen["U:\\Documents\\...programming_manual.pdf"]
```

But I cannot combine the two, `SystemOpen` returns a 1, but does not show anything and I cannot insert any command line parameters, again , `SystemOpen` returns a 1.

According to the documentation by Adobe it should be possible to set the zoom factor and the page number:

https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

I did find some references on StackExchange to open the explorer, but this scheme failed to open any other program outside the Windows-subdirectory I tried.

[How to call external commands with parameters on Win7?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64931/how-to-call-external-commands-with-parameters-on-win7)

On the other hand, `SystemOpen` opens essentially any `.exe` I tried so far, but, as stated above, fails with any attempts to add a parameter or even a file name.

**Edit and Summary:**

The suggestion by ***andre314*** is really nice and provides a process number, which one can use to kill the process once it is not required anymore.

```
StartProcess[{"C:\\...\\Acrobat\\Acrobat.exe", "/A", "page=79&zoom=100", 
  "U:\\Documents...\\users_guide.pdf"}]
```

Looking through my older notes, I saw that I usually open an `Excel` document with the command `Start` or `start`. Unluckily, I have no clue anymore who suggested this.

Command Prompt: `C:\Users\stelzer>start acrobat.exe` Check `C:\Users\stelzer>Help start`

Hence the following commands also work:

```
Run["start Acrobat.exe /A \"page=79\" \"U:\\Documents\\...users_guide.pdf\""]

Run["start Acrobat.exe /A \"page=79&zoom=100\" U:\\Documents\\...users_guide.pdf"]

Run["start Acrobat.exe" <> " /A" <> "\" page=79&zoom=100\"" <> 
  " U:\\Documents\\...users_guide.pdf"]
```

The spaces are required for the regular parsing process.

Comment: With AcroRd32.exe, I frequently use : `StartProcess[{"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Adobe\\Reader \
11.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe", 
     "/A", "page=1015", "PDF Path and FileName.pdf"}]` . It works fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works also with `Acrobat.exe`. I failed with `StartProcess`, since I  inserted the entire list of arguments in a single string. The quotes around `page` are also not necessary. Simply did not occur to me.

Comment: Multiple parameters can be combined with an ampersand `page=79&zoom=100`.

Comment: Why not just import the page into the notebook with `Import["file.pdf", {"PDF", "Pages", 42}]`?

Comment: Nice suggestion https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2490/swish, thank you. I usually need to look at several pages of a document. The part that interests me usually starts on page ##. I also highlight texts in my version of a PDF.

Comment: The `Run["start Acrobat.exe..." trick comes probably from Sal Mangano's book called "Mathematica cookbook", chapter 17.2, page 691

Comment: This might be of some use for a less platform-specific solution: https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html  It does not work with Mac Preview in that it does not jump to the specified page, but at least it does open the PDF without relying on Acrobat. I don't know if it works when Acrobat is the default PDF viewer. If it does, it would be a nice solution.