# Programmatically open a PDF to a specified page or tag

Tags: pdf-format

Is it possible to programmatically (in Mathematica) open a PDF to a specified page or open the PDF and jump to a tag somehow?

Comment: Does this help https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/216793/opening-pdf-file-on-a-specific-page?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for finding this.